# How laravel route:group wrapper works?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel has really nice features of routing which made our life so comfortable. I am so curious about this **Route::group()** wrapper. How does it work and how does Roue class inside group wrapper get the information at group parameters. Is it maintain any **global variable**?

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'audiobook',
    'middleware' => 'auth:api',
    'namespace' => 'Api\Audiobook'
], function () {
    Route::get('latest', 'AudioController@LatestAudioBook');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here's](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L342) the code that actually does it!

It's not modifying a "global" variable, or at least whether it's global or not is only incidentally relevant in that it's a design decision.

The routes are stored in a `Router` object, and you can read how the code works at the link above.